# TypeError: Must be real number not GKvariable

Tags: python, trigonometry, equation, gekko

I get an error when running the following code:

```
  from gekko import GEKKO
  m= GEKKO()
  sigma = m.Var()
  m.Equation((0.5*1.225*(Vt**2)*s*b)*(pb*(beta-sigma) \
             + Cndr*((((Vw**2)*Ss*CDy)/((Vt**2)*s) \
             - Cyb*(beta-sigma))/Cydr)) + Fw*dc*math.cos(sigma)==0)
  m.solve(disp=False)
  print(sigma.value)
```

In the above code, I want to find the value of the variable sigma. All other variables are constants that have been defined. While executing the above code, I got the following error.

```
m.Equation((0.5*1.225*(Vt**2)*s*b)*(x[10]*(beta-sigma) 
           + Cndr*((((Vw**2)*Ss*CDy)/((Vt**2)*s)
           - Cyb*(beta-sigma))/Cydr)) + Fw*dc*math.cos(sigma)==0)
TypeError: Must be a real number, not GKvariable
```

I think the issue is with `math.cos(sigma)`, because when I removed it - it worked.

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `math.cos` from the standard library, because as it says it wants an actual number (like `float` or `int`). GEKKO has its own functions that can handle `GKvariable`s. You should use `m.cos` instead of `math.cos`

https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html#equation-functions

> Special function besides algebraic operators are available through GEKKO functions. These must be used (not numpy or other equivalent functions):